# MVC how to convert GUID to string in model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We are updating some code in our solution, and I am running into an issue.  Previously, we passed a string into the code that was a GUID - it was entered in the front end as a string.  We want to replace that field with a drop down that will pass the GUID in automatically (too many mistakes in the string version).  Our CMS is Sitecore 7.2, and we have updated the code to pull the list of items that populate the dropdown.

The last piece of the puzzle is updating the models to take in the GUID from the form (the value WILL be a GUID, due to SC's mapping of values) and return a string to all of the subsequent code.  Manually updating each instance of the use of the GUID to use Convert.ToString is prohibitive.  Is there a way to just update the model?

Previously the model looked like this:

```
    [SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{36371859-7FF2-47D0-86F1-1579416AA584}", AutoMap = true)]
    public class NetForumEvent : Event, INetForumEvent
    {
    SitecoreField("NetForum ID")]
    public virtual string NetForumID { get; set; }
    ....
    }
```

Our updated model looks like this:

```
    [SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{36371859-7FF2-47D0-86F1-1579416AA584}", AutoMap = true)]
    public class NetForumEvent : Event, INetForumEvent
    {
    public MyLinkedItem NetForumID { get; set; }
    ....
    }

    [SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{36371859-7FF2-47D0-86F1-1579416AA584}", AutoMap = true)]
    public class MyLinkedItem : NetForumEvent, IMyLinkedItem
    {
    [SitecoreField("NetForum ID")]
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Any advice on how we can accomplish this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could create a different readonly property that returned the `Id` as a string rather than GUID, or you can change the type to `Object` and then you can have a custom getter/setter than sets GUID and gets as string

Comment: Thanks for the input, Jaxi.  I updated the code per your advice, but now I get a matching type error.  I posted the question over on the Sitecore StackOverflow site - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12726/sitecore-7-2-using-droplink since there may be an issue with my login in the dataflow.